# Selecting a subset of values in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, df, which contains a feature ('alpha') which is a list of letters {'A','B',...,'G'}

I'd like to select from df all rows which belong to a subset of this feature, say {'A','B','C'}.

What's the most 'pythonic' way to do this?

I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
subset = {'A','B','C'}
df1 = df[df['alpha'] == subset]
```

...but this generates an error:

```
"need more than 0 values to unpack"
```

Comment: Can you show an example of what alpha looks like? Is it a single feature (one letter per row?) or (list of letters?) ?

Comment: IIUC are you wanting `df1 = df1[df1['alpha'].isin(subset)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) to test for membership, example:

```
In [79]:
subset = {'a','b','c'}
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('abasbvggcgasgfdasgcdce')})
df[df['a'].isin(subset)]

Out[79]:
    a
0   a
1   b
2   a
4   b
8   c
10  a
15  a
18  c
20  c
```